# How do I limit the amount of images per row in a MaterializeCSS gallery

Tags: html, css, materialize

I am making an image gallery with MaterializeCSS but when images are different heights, it sets the images in the far right spot causing a lot of white space.

```html
<div id="recent" class="row">
    <div class="imagetab-grid" "col s3">
      <img class="materialboxed" src="img/no10.jpg" data-caption="">
    </div>
    <div class="imagetab-grid" "col s3">
      <img class="materialboxed" src="img/img_4332.jpg" data-caption="">
    </div>
    <div class="imagetab-grid" "col s3">
      <img class="materialboxed" src="img/no48.jpg" data-caption="">
    </div>
    <div class="imagetab-grid" "col s3">
      <img class="materialboxed" src="img/img_4447.jpg" data-caption="">
    </div>
    <div class="imagetab-grid" "col s3">
      <img class="materialboxed" src="img/img_4479.jpg" data-caption="">
    </div>
</div>
```

```css
.imagetab-grid {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 25%;
    padding: 10px;
    float: left;
}
    
.imagetab-grid img {
    width: 100%;
}
```

which causes this to happen:

[The fifth image gets pushed to the far right, then resets, with the third row continuing as normal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3LFUo.png)

It seems like either the `imagetab-grid`  class I wrote, or something built into Materialize is causing this problem to happen. Any suggestions on what to do?